# "Error: zoid destroyed all components↵" error in reactjs nextjs

Tags: reactjs, paypal, next.js

I have this paypal integration in my nextjs application. when I load the page everything loads well but when i navigate way from the page and back. It throws an error

```
unhandled_error: zoid destroyed all components↵
```

Paypal does not provide any additional information on this error at all.

My code is just a normal component

```
componentDidMount() {
    paypal
.Buttons({
  createOrder: (data, actions)=> {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            currency_code: "USD",
            value: amount,
          },
        }],
    });
  },
  onCancel: function(data){
    //console.log(data)

  },
  onError: function(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
})
.render("#paypal");
 }




<div id="paypal" className=""></div>
```

what am i doing wrong

Comment: These are very different questions. They come from the same code though. Especially this question. It's been racking up my brain so long because PayPal doesn't even provide any further explanation for the error.  Kindly upvote both questions to their previous ranking for it to be more visible

Answer (score 7):

This is related to a currently [open issue](https://github.com/krakenjs/zoid/issues/334) in the Paypal Buttons "Zoid" dependency, related to a bug in the way it's handling React components.

Currently, there is an [open PR](https://github.com/krakenjs/zoid/pull/335) that has not yet been completed/approved, but is on the way to solve this issue.
After this it's solved, next up the Paypal team will have the job of upgrading this dependency to finally fix the bug.

Disclaimer: I'm same who created the issue and submitted the PR, I'll be updating this comment once it's merged.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are implementing it the wrong way. PayPal has a [separate page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app/) with documentation for Single Page Applications.

Edit: Make sure you import React and ReactDOM in your Next.js app. As you can see in their React example.

Comment: I don't think anyone has been implementing it wrong. This piece of documentation has only been added recently. This should fix things though

Comment: You are right. Implementation seems to be correct. There were only some things missing.

Comment: @Dutch, Do you have any idea which things need to be added to work this fully?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of Paypal on embed JavaScript, create button script piece ran before paypal initialized. My solution is load the PayPal script before run create button script

```
function loadAsync(url: string, callback: () => void) {
  const s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src', url);
  s.onload = callback;
  document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstElementChild);
}

export const loadScriptPaypal = (html: string) => {
  const regex = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
  const scripts = html.match(regex);
  let pureHtml = html;
  const src = scripts[0].match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1];
  const func = scripts[1].replace(/<\/script>|<script>/g, '');
  loadAsync(src, () => {
    eval(func);
  });
  scripts.forEach(script => {
    pureHtml = pureHtml.replace(script, '');
  });
  return pureHtml;
};
```

Comment: Can we just load the script in the index.html? would that work? I tried it and have the same error, although I wait for a while then call the script.